# Microsoft graph - Access token validation failure. Invalid audience - Error

Tags: angular, authentication, microsoft-graph-api, access-token

I am trying to send mail using Graph API from Angular app.

In Azure active directory i have given the API permission for Mail.Send and other mail related things.

below is the code

```
const resource = {
    grant_type : 'client_credentials',
    clientID: '****************************',
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200/',
    validateAuthority : true,
    popUp: true,
    scopes: ['mail.send'],
    resource : 'https://graph.microsoft.com'
  };

  let murl : any
  murl = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/' + 'testuser@abcd.onmicrosoft.com' + '/sendMail';

  this.token = await this.msalService.acquireTokenSilent(resource)
      .catch((reason) => {
        // console.log(reason);
      });

      let header = new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.token.accessToken});
      let options = { headers: header };

      let resp =  this.http.post(murl, this.sendMailDet, options)
       resp.subscribe(
          (data)=>{
            console.log( data);
        }
        );
```

But when i send mail i get below error.

```
error: {code: "InvalidAuthenticationToken", message: "Access token validation failure. Invalid audience.",…}
code: "InvalidAuthenticationToken"
innerError: {date: "2021-01-06T04:52:20", request-id: "*********",…}
message: "Access token validation failure. Invalid audience."
```

I am using scopes: ['mail.send'] in resources still i am getting this error. Also i am using accessToken only from this.msalService.acquireTokenSilent(resource).

Token in jwt.ms showing aud as "aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
and  "scp": "Directory.Read.All email Mail.Read Mail.Read.Shared Mail.ReadBasic Mail.ReadWrite Mail.ReadWrite.Shared Mail.Send Mail.Send.Shared MailboxSettings.Read MailboxSettings.ReadWrite User.Export.All User.Invite.All User.ManageIdentities.All User.Read User.Read.All User.ReadBasic.All User.ReadWrite User.ReadWrite.All profile openid",

can anyone please help me to check this issue.

Comment: When `acquireTokenSilent` method is called, library first checks the cache in browser storage to see if a valid token exists and returns it. So in fact you are not getting an application token for Microsoft Graph here.

Comment: I notice that you are using `client_credentials` as grant_type, which means you want to use application token rather than user token. Is that right?

Comment: Hi @AllenWu , Initially when user log in there will be a token acquired for application. But to send mail i am taking different token with scopes included. And i am getting a different token. i verified in jwt.ms and found the scopes (which i mentioned in the last part. of question). So i think the token is proper. Or am i missing anything  ?

Comment: Well, actually i tried this from different sources, this client_credentials was there in that sample. My aim is to send mail from a user account. So do i have to change anything in grant_type : 'client_credentials' ?

Comment: No. The the token is **NOT** proper. That is why I'm asking you "you want to use application token rather than user token?". For a proper token which is acquired by `client_credentials` flow, there should be `roles` claim rather than `scp` claim. And `roles` claim is Application permission. `scp` claim is Delegated permission. You should be able to find these 2 type of permission when you add it in AAD app.

Comment: "Initially when user log in there will be a token acquired for application" Is this token for other resource / API? Not for Microsoft Graph API?

Comment: okk, to send the mail i need the Delegated permission? So client_credentials flow is required ? Sorry if am asking anything wrong, but to send the mail which token i should get ? Application token or user token ?

Comment: That initial token is used for user validation from ad, that is not graphAPI

Comment: Both Application token and user token can work. client_credentials flow gets the application token (Application permission). Auth code flow (or other interactive sign-in flow) gets user token (Delegated permission). So in your case, which one do you want?

Comment: "That initial token is used for user validation from ad" if so, you can only get an id token, not access token. Please refer to this sample to get access token (user token) for Microsoft Graph: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-angular.

Comment: In our app Auth Code flow we prefer. could you please tell what are the changes i have to do in my current code for that ?

Comment: See this part: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-angular#acquiretokensilent-acquiretokenpopup-acquiretokenredirect. The recommended pattern for most applications is to call `acquireTokenSilent` first, then catch the exception, and then call `acquireTokenPopup` (or `acquireTokenRedirect`) to start an interactive request.

Comment: Okk, Thanks for the link. I tried same kind thing but when ever i use   authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' , currently logged in user will log out automatically and this log in pop up shows. so i wanted to get a pop up to accept or reject the new authorities of the app. Like a pop up message to allow, 'Read.user','Send.mail' etc.  Let me try the link you have given, and i will update..

Comment: Okk, i think  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-angular#acquiretokensilent-acquiretokenpopup-acquiretokenredirect is what i have to try. Thank so much. let me check and update.

Comment: Sure. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Hi @nelsonthimothiyose Any updates?

Comment: Hi Allen, I tried different ways but it was not working., so i done a workaround, token and other details took from angular and send to API then mail send method done from API. I will update the code , answer this question, in case if it's helpful to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

I had to send the token from angular , because first the accept or cancel pop up will show. So had to handle from angular.
But it was giving me error mentioned in the question. So i created a API for that and send he token and other details from angular.

This is Angular part

data : object with From, To, CC, bcc, emailbody etc . using these values we create json email format in API

```
async sendmail(data): Promise<Boolean>  
  {

    let result : any ; 
    const resource = {
      clientID: environment.config.identityConfig.clientId , 
      redirectUri: environment.config.identityConfig.redirectUri , // 'http://localhost:4200/'
      validateAuthority : true,
      popUp: true,
      scopes: ['mail.send'],
      resource : 'https://graph.microsoft.com'
    };
    this.token = await this.msalService.acquireTokenSilent(resource)
    .catch((reason) => {
      console.log(reason);
    });

    this.atoken = this.token.accessToken;
    data.EMailAccessToken = this.token.accessToken;
    this.mailHttpService.post('/sendmailgapi', data, null, null, ApiUrl.FileService). // This is custom 
   subscribe((data) => {
     result = data; 
   });

   return result;
  }
```

Then in API,

this.applicationContext.GetGraphClient() : This another method from which using Client ID, tenant ID, ClientSecret  and using ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder , we create a Graph client.

sendMailDto : Passing object

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = this.applicationContext.GetGraphClient();
var fromEmail = sendMailDto.EMailFrom ; // 
var accessToken = sendMailDto.EMailAccessToken;
var message = createMessage(sendMailDto);
var restClient = new RestClient("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/" + fromEmail + "/sendMail");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken 
request.AddParameter("", message, ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = restClient.Execute(request);
```

I'm not sure if this is the correct method or not , but i had to do a workaround to solve the issue.